# Selenium2 wait for specific element on a page

Tags: wait, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium2(2.0-b3) web driver
I want to wait for a element to be present on the page. I can write like below and it works fine.

But I do not want to put these blocks for every page.

```
// Wait for search to complete
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                System.out.println("Searching ...");
                return webDriver.findElement(By.id("resultStats")) != null;
            }
        });
```

I want to convert it into a function where I can pass elementid and the function waits for a specified time and returns me true of false based on element is found or not.

public static boolean waitForElementPresent(WebDriver driver, String elementId, int noOfSecToWait){

}

I am reading that wait does not return till page is loaded etc, but I want to write the above method so that i can click on link to a page and call waitForElementPresent method to wait for element in next page before I do anything with the page.

Can you please help me write the method, I am getting into issue because I do not know how to restructure the above method to be able to pass parameters.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do that in C# (checks every 250 milliseconds for the element to appear):

```
private bool WaitForElementPresent(By by, int waitInSeconds)
{
var wait = waitInSeconds * 1000;
    var y  = (wait/250);
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    for (var x = 0; x < y; x++)
    {
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > wait) 
            return false;

        var elements = driver.FindElements(by);
        if (elements != null && elements.count > 0)
            return true;
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
bool found = WaitForElementPresent(By.Id("resultStats"), 5);  //Waits 5 seconds
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, new a class and add below method:

```
    public WebElement wait4IdPresent(WebDriver driver,final String elementId, int timeOutInSeconds){

    WebElement we=null;
    try{
        WebDriverWait wdw=new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);

        if((we=wdw.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see com.google.common.base.Function#apply(java.lang.Object)
             */
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return d.findElement(By.id(elementId));
            }
        }))!=null){
            //Do something;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Do something;
    }
    return we;

}
```

Do not try to implement interface ExpectedCondition<>, that's a bad idea. I got some problems before. :)

Answer (score 0):

from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits):

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
    }});
```